# InitState not executed at start

Tags: flutter, dart

Here you have part of my HomeScreen.dart file:

```
String _mi_email='';
String _mi_nombre='';
String _mis_apellidos='';
String _mi_foto='';
String _mi_clinica='';
String _mi_id='';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void getValues() async {
      SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      _mi_email = sharedPrefs.getString('email');
      _mi_clinica = sharedPrefs.getString('clinica') ?? "ninguna";
      _mi_nombre = sharedPrefs.getString('nombre') ?? "ninguno";
      _mis_apellidos = sharedPrefs.getString('apellidos') ?? "ningunos";
      _mi_foto = sharedPrefs.getString('foto') ?? "ninguna";
      _mi_id = sharedPrefs.getString('id') ?? "0";
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      getValues();
    }
...
```

What I need is to run getValues() every time when HomeScreen starts.

With my current code, it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to write the initState method outside the build methord or inside the _HomeScreenState.**
*And your code will look like this*

```
String _mi_email='';
String _mi_nombre='';
String _mis_apellidos='';
String _mi_foto='';
String _mi_clinica='';
String _mi_id='';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
  
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  void getValues() async {
      SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      _mi_email = sharedPrefs.getString('email');
      _mi_clinica = sharedPrefs.getString('clinica') ?? "ninguna";
      _mi_nombre = sharedPrefs.getString('nombre') ?? "ninguno";
      _mis_apellidos = sharedPrefs.getString('apellidos') ?? "ningunos";
      _mi_foto = sharedPrefs.getString('foto') ?? "ninguna";
      _mi_id = sharedPrefs.getString('id') ?? "0";
    }

    @override
    void initState() {      
      getValues();
      super.initState();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write method `getValues()`. into class `_HomeScreenState` not inside `build`.